# How to close window / widget properly after opening another window (.py file) in pyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

```
def run(self, path):
    subprocess.call(['pythonw', path])

def login(self):
    members = {'sample': 'sample'}
    username = self.username.text()
    password = self.password.text()

    if username in members:
        enteredPass = members.get(username)
        if password == enteredPass:
            self.run('inventory.py')
            #app.instance().quit()
            sys.exit()
        else:
            self.username.clear()
            self.password.clear()
            print("Invalid username and password.")
    else:
        self.username.clear()
        self.password.clear()
        print("Invalid username and password.")
```

I want to close the log-in window after the user enters the correct login details. The window tries to close but freezes and becomes unresponsive.

[image: This is what happens.]

My problem is how can I close the Log In form without causing it to be unresponsive? (If my code sample is lacking from where you can understand the problem, please tell me. Thank you!)

[image: Unresponsive. I want it closed after the user enters the correct log in details.]

Comment: what is inventory.py?

Comment: inventory.py is another gui window which can only be accessed if the login was successful.

Comment: try with my answer.

Comment: @lloydyu24. Why are you opening the second window using subprocess? Why don't you just import *inventory.py*?

Comment: @eyllanesc I will! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call function waits for the return code, so forcing to close the process that launches the new application generates that behavior. You should use `Popen` instead of `call`.

```
subprocess.Popen(['pythonw', path])
```